# jQuery scrollLeft in rtl direction - Different value in FireFox & Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, scroll

I have following simple **HTML** :

```
<div id='d1'>
    <div id='d2'>
        <table id='d3'>
            <tr>
                <td>T1</td>
                <td>T2</td>
                <td>T3</td>
                <td>T4</td>
                <td>T5</td>
                <td>T6</td>
                <td>T7</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<span id='s1'></span>
```

**CSS** :

```
    #d1{
        width: 400px;
        overflow: auto;
        direction: ltr;
    }
    #d2{
        width: 800px;
    }
    #d3{
        border:1px solid #ccc;
    }
    #d3 tr td {
        width:120px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    #s1 {
        font-size: 25px;
        color:#f00;
    }
```

**JS / jQuery** :

```
    var scroll;
    jQuery("#d1").on("scroll", function() {
        scroll = jQuery("#d1").scrollLeft();
        jQuery("#s1").html(scroll);
    });
    var scroll = jQuery("#d1").scrollLeft();
    jQuery("#s1").html(scroll);
```

[**See it Online**](http://www.v2.senatelecom.ir/scroll/index.php)

the red number is the value of scroll in any moment, the value is exactly the same in FireFox and Chrome, **but** when I change the direction to `rtl`, things change,  [**See it Online**](http://www.v2.senatelecom.ir/scroll/index-rtl.php),

- In FireFox in the first the scroll value is **0** and when scrolling to left, the value changes to **-400**
- But in Chrome, starts from **400** and when scrolling to left, the value changes to **0**

The question is How I must handle this difference when I'm trying to detect if scrollbar is in the first or in the end ? ( As you noticed, Chrome's first is 400, FireFox's first is 0 and ... )

Of course I can detect Browsers and do different calculation, like this [**StackOverflow Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614994/jquery-scrollleft-when-direction-is-rtl-different-values-in-different-browse) , But I don't want to do that, because this way I must check every **browsers** (FF, Chrome,Safari ...) and **IE** (6,7,8,9,10,11 ...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Better way to get the viewport of a scrollable DIV in RTL mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276619/better-way-to-get-the-viewport-of-a-scrollable-div-in-rtl-mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave a solution to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276619/better-way-to-get-the-viewport-of-a-scrollable-div-in-rtl-mode/24394376#24394376)

It uses feature detection, not browser detection.

Answer (score 4):

When direction is rtl, firefox scrolls from zero to negative numbers and chrome from positive numbers to zero. you should check the scroll side from these numbers when the website is initializing in the first load.

```
scrollNegative = elm.scrollLeft > 0 ? false : true;
```

After recognizing it. now you can detect where you should scroll by `scrollLeft`, right or left.