# Is there any specification for the value of Element.scrollLeft in RTL elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, right-to-left, cssom

Different browsers render different values for `Element.scrollLeft` in RTL elements. ([More details in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485043/jquery-scrollleft-in-rtl-direction-different-value-in-firefox-chrome)).

And [according to the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft), if the direction of the element is rtl, the `scrollLeft` should be 0 when the scrollbar is at its rightmost position. (Which means that Chrome's implementation is faulty).

But I couldn't find any specification that backs what the MDN mentions about this property in RTL mode.

Can anyone help me find one ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting the [MDN editor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/profiles/matspal@gmail.com) who [added the info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft$compare?from=69971&to=69972) about this behavior, he told me that the current spec adopts this model. ([CSS Object Model (CSSOM) View Module - working draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#scrolling-area-origin))

And the [discussion thread is here](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Aug/0156.html).