# scrollLeft doesn't work on IE and Firefox when using white-space:nowrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

my code dosen't work on IE and Firefox but works in Chrome:
the scroll left value on IE and Firefox = 0, why?

```
<body style="direction:rtl">
<div style="width:520px; margin:0 auto; background:#eee; height:120px;overflow:scroll " id="BookSliderContent">
    <div style="white-space:nowrap;">
        <div style="width:100px;height:100px; background-color:lightblue;margin:20px;display:inline-block">1</div>
        <div style="width:100px;height:100px; background-color:lightblue;margin:20px;display:inline-block">2</div>
        <div style="width:100px;height:100px; background-color:lightblue;margin:20px;display:inline-block">3</div>
        <div style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:lightblue; margin:20px; display:inline-block">4</div>
        <div style="width:100px;height:100px; background-color:lightblue; margin:20px; display:inline-block;">5</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var  ScrollLeft = 0;
  ScrollLeft = document.getElementById("BookSliderContent").scrollLeft;
  alert(ScrollLeft);
</script>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: It looks like others have had the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614994/jquery-scrollleft-when-direction-is-rtl-different-values-in-different-browse